# How can i use slug and id in routing and show the post link with slug only in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

### I want something like this

**routing.yml**

/bolg/{slug}/{id}

**post url**

/blog/slug-of-post

Comment: please, provide more details. and especially what you tried so far

Comment: @ Denis, I think above information is sufficient. The url of post will be /blog/slug/id . But i want to know, is it possible to remove id from post url using {id}  and {slug} parameter in routing.yml. I search the symfony documentation but there is nothing mentioned about what i want

Comment: Isn't the slug unique as well ? Then you just need `/blog/{slug}`

Comment: do not use yml - symphony will resign from using yml.

Comment: @Sam I see what you're trying to achieve, but the short answer is that you cannot do that. Whats the reason you don't want to use only the slug? like @Gregoire suggested? If it's because the slugs are not always unique, have you thought about appending the `ID` on the non-unique slugs?

Answer (score 0):

If `slug` is unique as well you can just have

```
routing.yml

/blog/{slug}
```

And then the url would be

```
/blog/slug-of-post
```

In your controller you then just need to do

```
$blogRepository->findBySlud($slug);
```

If the `slug` is not unique you should just ust your `id` as parameter then (but by definition `slug` should be unique)

Comment: @Gregiure, Thank you for your comment, i just wanted to know is it possible or not, i cant use slug only because i have already built in system using url format like /blog/id , and i want id and slug both in routing with url showing slug only. I might have to modify in nginx server to restrict id in url